# Parse a Bad JSON File

Tags: arrays, objective-c, json, swift, swift3

EDIT: Beautified JSON File

Following is the JSON File That I have hosted on local sever

```
{

"status": "success",

"error": "",

"response": "["{\"ip_id\":\"202\",\"ip_name\":\"P b \",\"small_desc\":\"Growth Hacker\",\"large_desc\":\"Sample description\",\"join_date\":\"\",\"vid_url\":\"https:\/\/www.theug.app\/user_videos\/pr_202.mp4\",\"img_url\":\"https:\/\/www.thnug.app\/user_thumbs\/s.jpg\",\"current_status\":\"0\",\"rate_per_hour\":\"1300\",\"currency\":\"\u20b9\"}","{\"ip_id\":\"217\",\"ip_name\":\"ss dd\",\"small_desc\":\"Talented\",\"large_desc\":\"Sample description2 \",\"join_date\":\"\",\"vid_url\":\"https:\/\/www.thug.app\/user_videos\/d.mp4\",\"img_url\":\"https:\/\/www.tsnug.app\/user_thumbs\/d.jpg\",\"current_status\":\"0\",\"rate_per_hour\":\"3850\",\"currency\":\"\u20b9\"}"]"}
```

I have made parsing using following code.

```
struct userData: Decodable {
  let ip_id : Int
  let ip_name : String
  let small_desc : String
  let large_desc : String
  let join_date : String
  let vid_url : String
  let img_url : String
  let current_status : Int
  let rate_per_hour : Int
  let currency : String
}

struct WebsiteDescription: Decodable {
    let status: String?
    let error: String?
    let response: [userData]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api-response.json"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            //perhaps check err
            //also perhaps check response status 200 OK

            guard let data = data else { return }
            print(data)
            do {
                let *users* = try JSONDecoder().decode(userData.self, from: data)
                print(users)

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I get The error message

```
Error serializing json: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "ip_id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"ip_id\", intValue: nil) (\"ip_id\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

1. How do I Get the array data in **var users**?
2. How can I use the var users though out the scope of my class?

Comment: Can you share beatified JSON data please?

Comment: `let *users* = try JSONDecoder().decode(userData.self, from: data)` => `let websiteDesc = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebsiteDescription.self, from: data)` that's the top level. Then `let response: [userData]` is a String in fact. It's JSON Stringified.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it's mandatory to decode the root object, `WebsiteDescription`

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebsiteDescription.self, from: data)
```

Second of all, you will run into another issue: The value for key `response` is a nested second level JSON **string** rather than a JSON array.

Don't do that. The JSON should look like

```
{"status":"success","error":"","response":[{"ip_id":"202","ip_name":"Prss Pus","small_desc":"Growth Hacker",...
```

Third of all, please name structs always with starting uppercase letter.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make changes to the json file. As it is a sample API response by company. Can you please suggest a way around?

Comment: Seriously blame the company for that amateurish mess. A workaround is to declare `response` as `String`, convert it to `Data` and run `JSONDecoder` a second time, now decoding `[UserData].self`

Comment: In regard to your ***edit*** now the JSON became invalid. And as **you** are hosting the file change the format to the syntax in my answer.